# Not able to bind web api service data to ng2-smart-table in angular 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular2-services

I am able to access my service and fetch the data but i am not sure how to bind it to a ng2-smart-table. I need to show the data in a grid view kind of structure.

Component code: table.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'ngx-table',
templateUrl: './table.component.html',  
styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss'],
providers: <any>[TableDataService]
})
export class TableComponent {
source: LocalDataSource;
settings = {
add: {
addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
      createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
    },
    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
    },
    delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
      confirmDelete: true,
    },
    columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'ID',
        type: 'number',
      },
      firstName: {
        title: 'First Name',
        type: 'string',
      },
      lastName: {
        title: 'Last Name',
        type: 'string',
      },
      username: {
        title: 'Username',
        type: 'string',
      },
      email: {
        title: 'E-mail',
        type: 'string',
      },
      age: {
        title: 'Age',
        type: 'number',
      },
    },
  };


  private customers:Customer[] = [];
  private errorMessage:any = '';

  constructor(private tableDataService: TableDataService){
    this.source = new LocalDataSource();
     this.tableDataService.getCustomerData()
   .subscribe(customers => this.customers = customers,
     error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
     debugger;
     this.source.load(this.customers); 
  }      

}
```

HTML code: table.component.html

```
<nb-card-body>
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="customers" (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)">
</ng2-smart-table>
```

Service code: table.service.ts

```
     getCustomerData():Observable<Customer[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:51654/api/Customer/')
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
} 
private extractData(res:Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || [];
}

private handleError(error:any) {

    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
    error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

Individually i am able to access the value customers  to html page, but when i am assigning to ng2-smart-table the source="customers" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `customers` with `source` in the `html`

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)">
</ng2-smart-table>
```

**If you still have the issue ,also try this**

After getting your data from service , load it like below

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.source.load(yourdata);
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  }, 0);
```

And you need to inject `ChangeDetectionRef`

```
 constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try so:

```
source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();
errorMessage: string;
constructor(private service: TableDataService) {
  this.service.getAdvertises()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.source.load(data);
      }, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```